# i want to append the rank value of each name of AuthorsInfo can do that?

Tags: jquery, arrays

Any help will be appreciated
i want to append the rank value of each name of AuthorsInfo can do that?

```
var AuthorsInfo=new Array();
AuthorsInfo.push({"name":"author1","rank":"Manager"});
AuthorsInfo.push({"name":"author2","rank":"author"});
 
 <script type='text/javascript'>
var authorName=$('.author-name').text();
for(i=0; i<AuthorsInfo.length; i++){
var getName=AuthorsInfo[i].name;
if(getName==authorName)     //i want to append the rank value of each name of AuthorsInfo can do that?
var authorRank = $(".author-rank");
var getRank=AuthorsInfo[i].rank;    // with that code it append the rank of the two AuthorsInfo array
authorRank.append(getRank);
}
            </script>
<div class='author-name'>author1 or author2</div>
                    <b class='author-rank'/>
// For example if the author name is author1 I want just author1 rank to be append in author rank or if the author name is author2 just auther2 to be append in author rank.
```

thanks for Any help.

Comment: Please include all relevant code, like html

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen  I am sorry ,I Edited it now

Comment: Are you trying to get both ranks into the same `<b class='author-rank'/>` ? if so what is not working

Comment: Fix your indentation. I think you want that `if` block to have 3 lines but it only has 1 because it lacks `{ }`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I do not want to get both ranks I want to get for the author1 his rank and for the aouther2 his rank not both ranks into the same code if the author name is author1 i want to get author1 rank else if the author name is author2 get author2 rank

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I just want to know how to get rank form array not both rank one rank by author name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem, your code was ok except for the missing brackets `{ }` in the `if` block.

```js
var AuthorsInfo = new Array();
AuthorsInfo.push({
  "name": "author1",
  "rank": "Manager"
});
AuthorsInfo.push({
  "name": "author2",
  "rank": "author"
});

var authorName = $('.author-name').text();
for (i = 0; i < AuthorsInfo.length; i++) {
  var getName = AuthorsInfo[i].name;
  if (getName == authorName) {
    var authorRank = $(".author-rank");
    var getRank = AuthorsInfo[i].rank;
    authorRank.append(getRank);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='author-name'>author1</div>
<b class='author-rank' />
```